# Rails build method breaks object ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a small problem I'm hoping to get some help with.

I have a block and a form positioned on the same page which works fine when the form is positioned below the block:

```
<% @project.tasks.each do |task| %>
   <%= link_to task.title, project_task_path(@project, task) %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for([@project, @project.tasks.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: 'Add a Task' %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

But when I position the form above the block I get an error stating my task ID is missing:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tasks", :id=>nil, :project_id=>"14"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

My best guess is that the build method in my form is the culprit. I've tried replacing .build with .new but it doesn't help.

Here is the create action from my tasks controller:

```
def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @task = @project.tasks.create(task_params)
  redirect_to @project
end
```

Does anyone know why I can't place the form above the block?

Comment: Because there are no tasks. Why not do that setup in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revised answer. I mocked this scenario up to check what's happening and the below is a working example that I believe achieves what you want.

Image of the end result:
[image]

I think the problem you were having is more from your controller setup. See the comments in the index action and the create action below to see how I've built up the task.

Routes:

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :projects do
    resources :tasks
  end
  root 'tasks#index'
end
```

Tasks Controller:

```
# app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb
# un-modified actions left out.
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /tasks
  # GET /tasks.json
  def index
    # Create the parent project from the url id
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    # Create a new task from the params from the form
    @task = @project.tasks.new
    # Get all tasks for your list
    @tasks = @project.tasks.all
  end

  # POST /tasks
  # POST /tasks.json
  def create
    # Create the parent project from the url id
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    # Create a new task from the params from the form
    @task = @project.tasks.new(task_params)
    # try and save the task.
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :index }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Tasks index view:

```
#app/views/tasks/index.html.erb
p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<%= form_for([@project, @task]) do |f| %>
  <% if @task.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@task.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this task from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @task.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<h1>Listing Tasks</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= task.name %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and example! I can see how this is a better system, keeping build/create/new methods in the controller. I learned a lot from this.